# integral of product of curve with itself in three dimensional

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vector-analysis

I have the next problem:

Let $\gamma:[0,1]\to R^3$ differentiable curve piecewise, and let $\Delta_r=\{(s,t)\in [0,1]^2| |\gamma(s)-\gamma(t)|<r\}$, i want to know if:

$$\int_{\gamma\times\gamma\cap \Delta_r}\gamma'(s)\gamma'(t)dsdt\geq 0 $$

I have the easy case when $r>diam(\gamma)$.

Thanks!

Comment: It seems that $\Delta_r$ is a subset of $[0,1]^2$, not of ${\mathbb R}^6$.

Comment: I'm sure I don't understand this.  Are you taking the dot product of $\gamma'(s)$ and $\gamma'(t)$?  And can you clarify the domain of integration?  It looks to me like $s=t$, which would mean the integrand is nonnegative.

Comment: As formulated, I could only downvote it: who is $\Delta_r$? This is a community: people asking for clarification want to help you; if you do not answer them, do not expect to be helped.

Comment: I tried to errase the question because I don´t need the answer now, but like I used bounties is imposible do this, so I only left this parts of the question, and nobody say nothing when it was complete.